# Why does sorl.thumbnail ImageField fail in the admin?

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have code that looks like this:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class Gallery(models.Model):
    pass

class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(upload_to='galleries')
```

In the admin:

```
class GalleryImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GalleryImage

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (GalleryImageInline,)
```

If I use the sorl.thumbnail as above, it is impossible to add images in the admin.  I get the validation error

```
Enter a list of values.
```

If I replace the sorl.thumbnail.ImageField with a plain django ImageField, everything works.

If I want sorl.thumbnail to clean up the cache thumbnails, I need to use it in the model, but if I use it in the model, I can't seem to add any images to need thumbnails.

Anyone else found and fixed this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, please see:

https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues/issue/14/#comment_642425

Answer (score -1):

Import statement should be:

> from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField

Comment: from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField
    from sorl.thumbnail.shortcuts import get_thumbnail, delete